# highlight fixed width block background color in vim

Tags: vim

I have an input file for a fortran code that needs input text in specific lines and within specific columns. I'd like to highlight the background of these fields when I type them in Vim.

I'm able to either specify a set of rows by

```
:highlight row ctermbg=green guibg=green
:match row /\%>5l.\%<9l/
```

or a specific set of columns by

```
:highlight col ctermbg=grey guibg=grey
:match col /\%>40c.\%<50c/
```

Is there a way to specify the row and column width for each field and highlight it a different color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the line and column restrictions to highlight a block:

```
:match block /\%>5l\%>3c.\%<8c\%<9l/
```

Note that `\%c` matches *byte indices*, not actual characters. Unless your Fortran code can only contain printable ASCII characters without `<Tab>`, you'd better match the screen width with `\%v` (what Vim calls *virtual column*).

For different matches, you have `:match`, `:2match`, and `:3match`. These are meant for interactive use; if you want to add the highlighting via a mapping, custom command, or autocmd, you should prefer the `matchadd()` / `matchdelete()` functions. They are slightly more involved to use, (you need to store the returned IDs to be able to delete them later), but you can use an arbitrary number of them.